# Python/Tkinter: drawing an Entry on top of a Button

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a Python/Tkinter app with a bunch of Buttons and I want to give the user an ability to edit the text on these buttons.

The most intuitive approach to me is to create an Entry widget on top of the button if the user right-clicks the button, and temporarily hide the button.

I did that and it's somewhat working but there is a problem. The button does not want to stay hidden. E.g. I create an Entry widget and it initially appears on top of the Button. Then, if I click inside the entry box, it briefly disappears (for a second or two), showing the button again, and then reappears. If I hit 'tab' and move focus out of the Entry, it disappears completely (exposing the button again) and only reappears when I click back into the entry/button area.

Am I doing something wrong / unintended, is that a bug, and is there a workaround?

Here's my Entry creation code ('self' is the button widget):

```
def on_mouse_rightclick(self, event):
    self.prev_state = self["state"]
    self.entry = Entry(self, {"width":8})
    self.entry.pack(side=TOP, anchor=W)
    self.entry.insert(0, self['text'])
    self.entry.bind('<Return>', self.on_entry_edit)
    self.entry.bind('<Escape>', self.on_escape)
    self['state'] = DISABLED
    self.lower(self.entry)
```

I tried to call `self.entry.lift()` and even to unbind `'<Button-1>'` temporarily from the button widget, with no effect.

I'm using 32-bit Python 2.7.9 on Windows.

Comment: The standard/more robust way of doing this is building your own custom widget by manipulating the Canvas object.

Comment: can you give a complete working example? Otherwise we have to guess at the other parts, and the other parts might be contributing to the problem.

Comment: @BryanOakley Short program exhibiting this behavior: http://pastebin.com/WvBbLsNj

Comment: @Alecg_O Can you be clearer, or link to some examples? I don't see how Canvas would help here (unless you're proposing that I shouldn't use standard widgets and should instead draw buttons / entry boxes & handle events by hand, which is something I'd very much rather avoid.)

Comment: Must be a bug, the short code you put works as intended on Python 2.7.6 on MacOs

Comment: Works fine on Python 2.6 and (with minor alterations) Python 3.1 on Debian 6.

Comment: Thanks. Must be a Windows-only bug then. I had it tested on three different machines (2.7.5/Win7, and 2.7.6/Win8, and 2.7.9/WinServer2012), with identical outcomes. I'll raise it directly with Python developers.
As a workaround, I've decided not to hide the Button but destroy it completely (and inherit CustomButton from Frame.) It's a bit more work but it solves the problem.

Comment: Have you tried `pack_forget`?